# Bluetooth Driver needed for Sony VAIO

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, sony-vaio

Bluetooth driver and software for sony vaio vpceb14 for windows 7 32 bit is needed

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you go to [VAIO After-Sales Support page](http://support.vaio.sony.eu/computing/vaio/index.aspx?l=en_GB&m=0) and find your model there.

I've had success with "Log-in Option 2" on the right-hand side.

1. Choose your **Category** (presumably VPCEB)
2. Choose your **Model** (presumably one of VPCEB1A4E or VPCEB1B4E),
3. Click **Log in>**
4. Click on the appropriate icon, depending on the machine's original OS version (e.g. Downloads, Updates or similar), and you should then see a link to Bluetooth drivers.